# How to replace a Python 3 installation with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I already have Python 3 installed on the server machine, and I want to replace that with Python 2.7 as the code I have to deploy is complaint with Python 2.7.

What command should I run so Python application.py runs it on Python 2.7?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you _replace_ your python version as that might (most probably) break something on the machine. Instead, install something like _virtualenv_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To control which version of Python, add this line to the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

Then execute the script directly using `/path/to/my/script`, and thanks to the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (first line) it will run in Python 2. (The script also needs to be executable for this to work.)

Alternatively, execute your python script without above first line using your chosen Python version:

```
python2 /path/to/my/script
```

Similar steps will enable you to use Python 3 instead of 2, assuming your script imports are 3.

Comment: Note for newbies: you don't need to call `/usr/bin/python2`; just `python2` is fine.